# IndexError: list index out of range using pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using pip 1.5.4 and I'm trying to install Google Client API for python using the following command:
    `sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

But I'm getting an exception which says:

```
Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, 
in main status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 
278, in run requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, 
force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1260, in 
prepare_files)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried upgrading pip using the following command:
    `sudo pip install -U pip`

But it gives the same exception as above.Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's duplicated i think: 
[pip install broken (pkg_resources.find_distribution returns empty list in req.py-prepare_files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901687/pip-install-broken-pkg-resources-find-distribution-returns-empty-list-in-req-py)

So, solution can be:

```
pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute
```

Comment: Since "--no-use-wheel" renamed to "--no-binary". So this command should be like "pip install --no-binary --upgrade distribute"

Comment: I got the same problem but with pip3, try this but doesn't work what should i do in that case?