# Installing torch using PIP

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install the python module Torch in Pycharm using PIP.

I have tried using commands:

```
pip install torch
pip3 install torch
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

All of these commands produce the same error:

```
 File "......\snake\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3
-py3.6.egg\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 90, in dist
    self.req.source_dir))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please may you tell me how to fix this error, or what causes it?

Comment: There may be an issue with your `pip` installation. Have you tried re-install ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548957/can-i-force-pip-to-reinstall-the-current-version

Comment: Just googled "pip install torch indexerror list index out of range", does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47011935/9063935) help at all?